# Coding for quiz site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to recreate the quiz format of this site,   [quizsite](http://quizible.com/quiz/guess-the-logo/20155)

The part I'm struggling with is the auto check of the answer and sending of the box that contains the answer green when the answer is correct.

Can anyone shed any light on the code needed for the auto checking part of this site?

Comment: Show us your code or, at least, what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should research what is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and DOM manipulation.

I suggest you to look for [jquery](http://jquery.com/) which is one of the best js framework.

Browser will send data through ajax to the page which checks the answer and that page gives a result back to trigger the DOM manipulation.

Comment: hi, thanks for the pointers, i'm already looking into AJAX and DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

This requires AJAX to check with the server that the answer is correct without reloading the page.  AJAX is fairly simple to learn but too lengthy to explain here so look here for a good tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Basically, on blur of the textbox you would send an AJAX request to the server for validation. The server would then send a response and depending on the response (valid/invalid) you would change the CSS property on the textbox i.e either change the background-color to green or red.